# Mongoexport - как правильно? По одной коллекции неудобно

Tags: mongodb, коллекции

Была задача сбэкапить содержимое базы с сервака. На серваке MongoDB версии 3.*
Для сего действа я заюзал стандартную утилиту mongoexport, НО: при попытке бэкапа всей базы (т.е. как я думал, что если не указать коллекцию, он сбэкапит всё) он ругается, говорит, мол, покажи, какую коллекцию экспортировать. Пришлось все 30+ коллекций по очереди вручную прописывать. Вследствие чего и возник вопрос - а как проще можно? Не, ясен пень, что можно на PHP (например) набросать скрипт, который получит список коллекций, засунет их в массив, потом в foreach для каждой выполнит mongoexport с указанием имени файла, это всё понятно. Вопрос в другом - есть ли какое-то стандартное решение, пусть даже через тот-же mongoexport? Я просто не впервые сталкиваюсь с этим, и циферки в версии Монги с тех пор неплохо так подросли, а проблема осталась. Может, я что-то упустил?

P.S. На серваке Debian, на рабочем компе Ubuntu. Если вдруг это важно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы упустили утилиту [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/). Простейший поиск вам бы дал вот этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605781/238336):

Сделать backup БД со всеми коллекциями в директорию:

```
mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>
```

Восстановить backup из директории с дампом:

```
mongorestore -d <database_name> <directory_backup>
```

Comment: Спасибо, когда-то использовал mongodump, он создаёт BSON-файлы. Но, насколько я помню, восстанавливать из них всё равно по одной коллекции нужно.